# The future progressive without a reference to a particular future time

Tags: future-tense, progressive-aspect

The future progressive is common to say that some action will be in progress in a ***particular future moment***.

But what if we don't have an appropriate reference to a particular future time?

I've tried to invent a suitable example, but I can't. Does such construction make any sense at all?

Comment: If you can give a rough example of the kind of phrase you are looking for, it would then be easier to answer accurately.

Comment: *The future progressive is common to say that some action will be in progress in a particular future moment.* - **Not always.** It may just talk about the future (though future is that particular time!). Do I need to read the question further now? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your concern, but if you are asking about what to say when a specific future time is not stated, you could use phrases like *in the near future* or *later on* that are not time specific.

> I will be going to the beach *in the near future*.
>   I will be going to the movies *after awhile/later on*.

Comment: The sentence _I will go to the movies later on_ seems to me a bit strange. I think _I'm going to go to the movie_ or _I'm going to the movie_ is more natural, isn't it?

Comment: is the _will_ used as announced speaker's decision?

Comment: @Dmitry There's nothing strange about *I will go to the movies*, but it's simple future, not future perfect/progressive. The *will* indicates that it's in the future, and conveys that the speaker is confident in or assured of the occurrence.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Right you are. I edited my answer for the correct tense.